# Vb.net extract text from image

Tags: vb.net, winforms, bitmap, ocr

i want to extract text from an image. For example:

[image]

return: `12345678910`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: MODI from Office 2007 _might_ be an option if your environment supports this.

Comment: i tried to use the Aspose.OCR, but i dont want web application

Comment: I don't see why Aspose.OCR should be web only.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this via [Tessnet2](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/), which is an open source wrapper around the Tesseract engine.